# discord ban command available to all users node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am working on a discord bot i made a ban command but it is available to all users i am using discord.js 12.0

This is my code

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();

const express = require("express")
const app = express()

app.get("/", (req, res) =>{
  console.log("helloe")
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Ready")
})


client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Beast Bot is ready');
    client.user.setActivity('Discord Ping Messages || ~help || (Made by CaptainBeast#1394)  ', { type:"WATCHING"}).catch(console.error)

});




const ownerId = "602113193489203232";
const owner2Id = "725629309854679092";


client.on("message", async message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return false;

    if (message.mentions.has(ownerId)) {
       
        message.reply(`Thanks for pinging my owner you will be banned with in 24 hours :))`);
    
    
    };
    if (message.mentions.has(owner2Id)) {
       
      message.reply(`Thanks for pinging my co-owner you will be banned with in 24 hours :))`);

  };
  if(message.content.startsWith("~mute")) {
    if(message.member.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS"))
    {
      message.reply(`Thanks for pinging my co-owner you will be banned with in 24 hours :))`);

    }
  };


  if (!message.guild) return;

  // if the message content starts with "!ban"
  if (message.content.startsWith('$ban')) {
    // Assuming we mention someone in the message, this will return the user
    // Read more about mentions over at https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/MessageMentions
    const user = message.mentions.users.first();
    // If we have a user mentioned
    if (user) {
      // Now we get the member from the user
      const member = message.guild.members.resolve(user);
      // If the member is in the guild
      if (member) {
        /**
         * Ban the member
         * Make sure you run this on a member, not a user!
         * There are big differences between a user and a member
         * Read more about what ban options there are over at
         * https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=ban
         */
        member
          .ban({
            reason: 'They were bad!',
          })
          .then(() => {
            // We let the message author know we were able to ban the person
            message.channel.send(`Successfully banned ${user.tag}`);
          })
          .catch(err => {
            // An error happened
            // This is generally due to the bot not being able to ban the member,
            // either due to missing permissions or role hierarchy
            message.channel.send('I was unable to ban the member');
            // Log the error
            console.error(err);
          });
      } else {
        // The mentioned user isn't in this guild
        message.channel.send("That user isn't in this guild!");
      }
    } else {
      // Otherwise, if no user was mentioned
      message.channel.send("You didn't mention the user to ban!");
    }
  }












});


// inside a command, event listener, etc.
const help = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#0099ff')
    .setTitle('Commands')
    .setURL('')
    .setAuthor('CaptainBeast', 'https://www.clipartmax.com/png/full/307-3072086_discord-icon-discord-icon-png.png')
    .setDescription('Here are the list of some available commands')
    .setThumbnail('https://www.clipartmax.com/png/full/307-3072086_discord-icon-discord-icon-png.png')
    .addFields(
        { name: 'Commands', value: ':) commands' },
        { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' },
        { name: '~help', value: 'Displays list of available commands', inline: true },
        { name: '~ping', value: 'sent pong ', inline: true },
    )
    .addField('More stuffs coming soon', 'the bot is still under development', true)
    .setImage('')
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter('Made by CaptainBeast#1394', 'https://www.clipartmax.com/png/full/307-3072086_discord-icon-discord-icon-png.png');
    
    

  
    
  

const prefix = "~";
client.on("message", (message) => {
  // Exit and stop if it's not there
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

  if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "help")) {
    message.channel.send(help);
    
  } else
  if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "foo")) {
    message.channel.send("bar!");
  }
  if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "ping")) {
    message.channel.send("pong!");
  }
});

client.login('censored')
```

This is my whole code

Comment: Please don't fill your question with spam, the description rules exist for a reason.

Answer (score 2):

After your if condition to know if it's the ban command, you don't look at the permission of the person who wrote the message.
You need just to add the condition

For Disord.js V12

```js
if (message.member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) {
    ...
}
```

For Discord.js V13

```js
if (message.member.permissions.has("BAN_MEMBERS")) {
    ...
}
```